# Permission issue in WSL2 and gnupg

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg, wsl-2

I'm trying to generate GPG key and move that key to outside of WSL2.

1. Generate GPG key and its revocation cert in WSL2
2. Export keys to Windows by command below:

`gpg2 --export-secret-keys --armor "GPG_PUBLIC_ID" > ~/secret-key.asc`

This command successfully generates .asc file with permission `-rw-r--r--`
And my destination directory(`/mnt/c`) has permission of `drwxrwxrwx`

So permission seems sufficient.
However, export has failed when the key is exported to outside of WSL or copied to outside of WSL.

`gpg2 --export-secret-keys --armor "GPG_PUBLIC_ID" > /mnt/c/secret-key.asc`

This command gives error as follows: `zsh: permission denied: /mnt/c/secret-key.asc`

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and package manager is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root directory fo Windows (C:\) has higher security contraints than other directories. `drwxrwxrwx` might not reflect real permission in Windows. You should not write files in Windows root directory unless you have a very strong reason to do so.

Try

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys --armor "GPG_PUBLIC_ID" > /mnt/c/temp/secret-key.asc
# Create C:\temp in Windows if it does not exist.
```